# Values from `.tfvars` not getting loaded

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I am new to terraform and building my first terraform script to launch instances in GCP. Values from `terraform.tfvars` are **not** being loaded and only default values from `variables.tf` are being loaded. Below are the commands that I am using to run to run the script. Can someone let me know the mistake I am doing?

```
terraform plan -var-file=terraform.tfvars
terraform apply-var-file=terraform.tfvars
```

Below is the file structure

```
├── gcp_instance
│   ├── gcp_instance.tf
│   └── variables.tf
├── main.tf
└── terraform.tfvars
```

My `main.tf` file

```
module gcpinstance {
  source = "./gcp_instance"
}
```

my `gcp_instance.tf` file

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "3.5.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "google" {
  region      = "${var.gcp_region}"
  project     = "${var.gcp_project}"
  zone        = "${var.gcp_zone}"
  credentials = "${var.gcp_credentials}"
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "vm_instance" {
  count        = length(var.instance_name)
  name         = var.instance_name[count.index]
  machine_type = element(var.instance_type, count.index)

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image =  element(var.instance_image, count.index)
    }
  }

  network_interface {
    network = "${var.gcp_network}"
  }
}
```

my `variables.tf` file

```
variable "gcp_project" {
  description = "Google Cloud Platform project"
  default     = "test"
}

variable "gcp_region" {
  description = "Google Cloud Platform's selected region"
  default     = "us-central1"
}

variable "gcp_zone" {
  description = "Google Cloud Platform's selected Zone"
  default     = "us-central1-f"
}

variable "gcp_credentials" {
  description = "Credential file to be used for this project"
  default     = "test"
}

variable "instance_tags" {
  type = list
  default = ["application1", "application2"]
}

variable "instance_type" {
  type = list
  default = ["f1-micro","f1-micro"]
}

variable "instance_name" {
  type = list(string)
  default = ["application1", "application2"]
}

variable "instance_image" {
  type = list
  default = ["debian-cloud/debian-9","debian-cloud/debian-9"]
}

variable "gcp_network" {
  description = "Network to be used"
  default     = "default"
}

variable "gcp_network_global_cidr" {
  description = "CIDR for the Instances"
  default     = "10.0.0.0/24"
}
```

my  `terraform.tfvars` file

```
gcp_project = "test"
gcp_region  = "us-central1"
gcp_zone    = "us-central1-f"

gcp_credentials = "test.json"
instance_tags = ["application1", "application2", "application3"]
instance_type = ["f1-micro", "f1-micro", "f1-micro"]
instance_name = ["application1", "application2", "application3"]
instance_image = ["debian-cloud/debian-9", "debian-cloud/debian-9", "debian-cloud/debian-9"]

gcp_network = "default"
gcp_network_global_cidr = "10.0.0.0/24"
```

Comment: What errors are you getting, if any?

Comment: @tilleyc i am not getting any errors, values from terraform.tfvars are not being loaded and only default values from variables.tf